# change the xlink:href of an <image> in a svg, through a classic <a> link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dom, svg

I have an SVG in my webpage (I use PHP):

```
<svg width="500px" height="500px" xml:lang="fr"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<image width="500" height="500" xlink:href="img1.jpg" opacity="0.35" />
</svg>
```

I would like to be able to change the `xlink:href` variable when clicking on a link (and without reload the webpage), something like:

```
<a href=#" onclick="changexlinkhref(img2.jpg)">change with img2</a>
```

However, I wonder what would be the code of the JavaScript function `changexlinkhref(img){}`?

For now, I do not use JQuery on my project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You'll need to put the img2.jpg argument in single quotes Then something like this should do it provided you only have one image element on the page.

```
function changexlinkhref(value) {
  document.querySelector("image").setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', value);
}
```

These days most browsers support href in the null namespace as well leading to the simpler

```
function changexlinkhref(value) {
  document.querySelector("image").setAttribute('href', value);
}
```

Although as far as I know, Inkscape and Batik still don't yet support it.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Robert Longson answer, if you set the value through js and not html5 you should just set `href` instead of `xlink:href` with the correct namespace.

It should be set like this:

```
setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', url);
```

Answer (score 4):

## `xlink:href` got depreciated

This JavaScript method is what works now:

```
….setAttribute('href', url);
```

Obviously, `"href"` with double quotes will also work.

Answer (score 0):

This will change the image each time it gets clicked.
If you need to use the click event you need to use the div container. 
Otherwise you could assign the `onclick` directly to the `<svg>`

```
<div id="d0"  onclick="next(0);">
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="154" height="205" ">
  <image x="0" y="0" width="154" height="205" href="photo.webp"/>
 </svg>
</div>

<script>
var pointer = 0;
var image = [];
var img = {0:['image0.webp','image1.webp','image2.webp','image3.webp','photo.webp]};
image[id] = document.getElementById('s' + id);

function next(id){
  image[id].setAttribute('href',img[id][pointer++]);
  if (pointer == 4){pointer = 0;}
}
</script>
```