# Cordova svg <image xlink:href/> throws Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND [file:///android_asset/www/undefined]

Tags: javascript, image, cordova, svg, href

I'm building an application with cordova, I have an SVG element in my html with an  tag in it. the url of the image comes from my firebase storage, the url works fine. if I directly put the url in my html:

```
<image xlink:href="url"/>
```

it works fine and it displays the image. (testing on android, debug).

but what I need to do is set the xlink:href trough javascript so i'm doing:

```
document.getElementById("imageID").setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', "the url");
```

I've also tried:

```
document.getElementById("imageID").setAttribute('xlink:href', 'the url');
```

but both these attempts throw this error:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND [file:///android_asset/www/undefined]

and display the standard url not found image

I cant for the life of me figure why though, the image url works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change the xlink:href of an <image> in a svg, through a classic <a> link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772225/change-the-xlinkhref-of-an-image-in-a-svg-through-a-classic-a-link)

Comment: doesn't work, also should have added that I have multiple image tags, so I need to distinguish between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, it was an async problem where my retrieve URL function wasn't finished at the point I am calling the url.